# Rails Routing: REST Verb Aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there an easy way to change the default method that a particular HTTP Verb maps to when dealing with RESTful routing in rails? Let's say each of my model controllers has a *delete* action instead of *destroy*, however when I use:

```
link_to "Delete", some_object, :method => :delete
```

Rails does what it's supposed to and routes to the *destroy* action of my resource's controller. Instead, I'd like to route to an action named *delete*. That's it.

I know I can just use ruby's **alias** in my controllers or add a custom member route for each of my resources, but is there an easier way to do this to make the changes app-wide? Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in the answer out of curiosity. However, the fundamental question is - why do you want to do this? Why break convention?

Comment: I'm not one to mess with convention, but I've been updating an old app to Rails 3, which uses a **delete** method instead of  **destroy** in its controllers. I'm looking to update routes and views first before messing with any of the controller code. This change would be a _very_ temporary thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use alias in your ApplicationController, then that will flow through to your other controllers that inherit from it.

That will function the way you want it to.

Warning: rails is opinionated software and generally you won't want to step too far out of the way rails works. And rails loves standard REST actions.